# Trianglify.js generate backgrounds on server side (ruby)

Tags: ruby, therubyracer, execjs, trianglify

I'm trying to generate triangle-pattern backgrounds server-side (ruby) using [trianglify.js](http://qrohlf.com/trianglify/) and [gem 'therubyracer'](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) (also tried execjs - same error)

I use the following code

```
 require 'v8'
 cxt = V8::Context.new
 cxt.load('trianglify.js')
 png = cxt.eval("var pattern = Trianglify({width: 200, height: 200}); return pattern.png()")
 puts png
```

Loaded script
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/1.0.1/trianglify.js

Error

```
V8::Error: require is not defined
at trianglify.js:8:16
```

Comment: That javascript file is trying to use NodeJS's function `require`, which is not defined in `libv8` as a javascript function.

Comment: Found alternative https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/76342abc327062128604